# Can I use '==' with pipe ( | ) in angular2 templates?

Tags: html, angular

I have written a pip named `wordsAllDone` to check whether all the words are marked as `done`, and its output is a boolean value.
However, I want to let this button hide when `words | wordsAllDone` is `true` and show when it's `false`.

```
<button *ngIf="words | wordsAllDone == false" (click)="startReview()">START</button>
```

But angular2 show a parse error:

```
<button [ERROR ->]*ngIf="words | wordsAllDone == false" (click)="startReview()" ion-button item-right outline>START</button>:ReviewPage@27:20
Parser Error: Unexpected token ==, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 22 in [words | wordsAllDone == false] in ReviewPage@27:20
```

Can I use the `==` operator with `|` at the same time?

Comment: Have you tried using parentheses to clarify what you want - `(words | wordsAllDone) == false`?

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. @jonrsharpe

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you'd add this as an answer awmleer could accept it and the question would be shown as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add parentheses to make it clear that you want to compare the return value from the pipe:

```
*ngIf="(words | wordsAllDone) == false"
```

Note you could also use `!` rather than comparing equality with `false`:

```
*ngIf="!(words | wordsAllDone)"
```